# How do I make aliases for already existing commands?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So, I'm making a Minecraft mod that allows make aliases for exising commands, like `/tp`, `/spawnpoint`, `/setblock`, etc.., as well as making many commands in one that will be executed by the order, like so:

```
/alias add sun "time set day" "weather clear"
```

I've already made the base of `/alias` command itself, but I still have no idea, how to make the functionality of it.

```java
public class CommandAlias extends CommandBase {

    private final List<String> aliases = Lists.newArrayList(Reference.MODID, "alias", "al");

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "alias";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsage(ICommandSender sender) {
        return "/alias add|remove|edit <alias> <command(s)>";
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getAliases() {
        return aliases;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkPermission(MinecraftServer server, ICommandSender sender) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(MinecraftServer server, ICommandSender sender, String[] args) throws CommandException {
        // sender.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("Hi " + sender.getName() + "!"));

        if (args.length < 1) {
            sender.sendMessage(new TextComponentString(TextFormatting.RED + "Invalid arguments!"));
            return;
        }

        String alias = args[0];
        String cmd = args[1];

        if (args[0] == "add"){
            // something
        } else if (args[0] == "remove" || args[0] == "delete"){
            // something
        } else if (args[0] == "edit"){
            // something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use hashmaps, where the key will be alias and value will be the command

Comment: @noname ok, but how the alias will be registered?

Comment: `HashMap<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<String, String>(); aliases.put("alias_name", "command"); // alias registration, aliases.get("alias_name"); // calling command by alias`

Comment: @noname you've just declared the variable or something, not registrated the command (alias). usually, commands are registering in FMLServerStartingEvent, like that:

`@Mod.EventHandler
    public void init(FMLServerStartingEvent event){
        event.registerServerCommand(new CommandAlias());
    }`
but I need registration in the CommandAlias class without that event, because then need its own class to registrate on

Comment: I gave you the other way around, but if you want to use something else check `Design patterns` especially `Command Desing patter` can be helpful I think

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a couple of things:

1. A list of all aliases that are registered
2. An alias executor that will execute the aliased command when it is typed
3. Register the alias commands to bukkit

Here's a bit of a sample of this:

1. A list of aliases

```java
HashMap<String, String> aliasList = new HashMap<String>;
```

When you add an alias you will need to add it to the command it is aliasing:

```java
aliasList.put(myAliasString, commandToReplace);
```

2. An alias executor that will execute the aliased command when it is typed

```java
executeAlias(String alias, ICommandSender sender, String[] args) {
    if(aliasList.contains(alias) {
        String aliasedCommand = aliastList.get(alias);

        // Here you will need to convert the args array to a spaced string (if needed). 
        // Then send the command:
        Bukkit.getServer().dispatchCommand(sender, commandString);
    }
}
```

3. Register the commands when they come in:

```java
if (args[0] == "add"){
    // Make the AliasListener have the code from part 2
    Bukkit.getCommand(args[1]).setExecutor(aliasListener)

    // Store the alias and the command it replaces in the list.
    this.aliasList.put(args[1], args[2])
}
```